# Spring MVC Service DAO architecture

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Should each service call one DAO e.g. CustomerService->CustomerDAO or we can use dataService can call CustomerDAo and ProjectDAO as example

Comment: It's up to you, Spring has no limitation on this point. This choice may depend on the size of the project, on architectural decisions, ...

Answer (score 2):

There is no restriction of calling Dao layers from one Service or more then one services, also it depends on the current requirement

Generally the DAO is as light as possible and exists solely to provide a connection to the DB, sometimes abstracted so different DB back-ends can be used.

The service layer is there to provide logic to operate on the data sent to and from the DAO and the client. Very often these 2 pieces will be bundled together into the same module, and occasionally into the same code, but you'll still see them as distinct logical entities.

As you said `Should each service call one DAO e.g. CustomerService->CustomerDAO or we can use dataService can call CustomerDAo and ProjectDAO as example`

So here depends on the requirement if DataService just need data from CustomerDAo e.g list of customers then you should directly use CustomerDAO in DataService, But if you need the some kind of calculation or else in your customers data and it is present on CustomerService(basically this kind of things implemented on Dao corresponding Service) then you go for CustomerService.